# Implementing piping in c++

Tags: c++, pipe, exec, fork

I'm trying to implement piping in C++. My method `piped` takes in an array of arguments along the line of `yes | head -10 | wc`. It creates pipes number of processes and changes the image of the processes to, following that example, `yes`, `head -10`, and `wc`. Then it creates pipes-2 pipes and redirects the input and output of the processes to the pipes.

It's not working correctly, and just prints each command separately without redirecting input/output.

```
#include "piped.h"

using namespace std;

void piped(char *stringList[], int pipes)
{

//stringList[] is list of arguments seperated by |
//pipes = number of arguments

pid_t processList[256];
char *curList[256];

//Create a new process for each job using fork

for(int i = 0; i < pipes; i++){
    processList[i] = fork();

    if (processList[i] < 0) {
        cerr << "Couldn't create process\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}

int j = 0;

//Replace the image of each process with the appropriate commands

for(int i = 0; i < pipes; i++){

    pid_t pid = processList[i];

    if(pid == 0){

    char *check = stringList[j];

    int k = 0;

    while(true){

        curList[k] = check;
        j+=1;
        k+=1;

        check = stringList[j];

        if(check == NULL || strcmp(check, "|") == 0){
            break;
        }
    }

    j+=1;

    curList[k] = NULL;

    execvp(curList[0], curList);
    cout << "Exec error!\n";
    exit(1);

    }
}


//Piping
//create n-2 pipes 
//redirect the output of job i to the write end of pipe i
//redirect the input of job i to the read end of pipe i

for(int i = 0; i < pipes-1; i++){

    int pipefd[2];

    if(pipe(pipefd) < 0){
        cout << "Pipe error!\n";
    }

    int pid1 = processList[i];
    int pid2 = processList[i+1];

    if(0 == pid2){
        //Child 2
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0],1);
        close(pipefd[0]);

    }

    if(0 == pid1){
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1], 0);
        close(pipefd[1]);
    }

}

//Wait for all jobs to terminate

for(int i = 0; i < pipes; i++){
    pid_t pid = processList[i];
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}
}
```

Comment: Amongst other problems, you exec your child processes _before_ redirecting I/O.

Comment: I thought of that, but the specifications for the project made it seem ok. Would it be sufficient to simply move the for loop that does the exec below the piping for loop?

Comment: Further, each child execs each command, which means they'll all just exec `yes` and then exit.

Comment: You need to understand what the code is doing as well as what's required - start by understanding what happens when you call `fork`, because I don't think it's what you expect.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll look into fork more.

Comment: So I believe I was missing an if check in my loop that handles exec().. I was confirming that the current pid is equal to 0. When I add that fix, I get some weird results. It's no longer printing any command more than once, but if I run for example ls -a | pwd, it prints ls -a and then tries to use pwd as a file descriptor for ls

Comment: The initial problem is that the first iteration of your fork loop gives you two processes (the parent and child) continuing execution at the same point. Then _each_ of these enters the second iteration, creating a further 2 processes. The whole logic of this section is wrong. Eventually, _all_ of your `2^pipes` processes start the second loop at the same point ...

Comment: PS. Consider using `strace -f` or similar to follow what's going on

Comment: From what I understand, the way I've structured my code will not work and I should basically start from scratch. Everything should probably be happening within the same for loop to stop duplication?

Comment: That would probably work fine, yes. Good luck!